# Galois extension of Q(roots of unity) over Q

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

could someone please explain the solution to me?

1) I don't understand why they know they could send epsilon to (epsilon)^i.
2) Did they assume the Galois group is Z/4Z because the order of Galois group has order 4 and so we could assume it is isomorphic to a group of order 4?
3) How did they calculate the "fourth line", i.e. (sigma_2)^4 = (sigma_1)(16) = ...?

Thank you very much!!

[image]

Comment: That's a zeta by the way

Comment: I really don't even understand what $\;\sigma_1(16)\;,\;\;\sigma_3(8)\;$ mean in this context... Where did you take the above from?

Comment: @DonAntonio The question itself is from Abstract Algebra by Artin (2 ed.), Question 7.9 (pg.507). The solution set is from Harvard: http://www.math.harvard.edu/~ctm/home/text/class/harvard/123/02/html/home/solns/sset-11.pdf

Comment: @Wilson Thanks, but it's the same for me: $\;\sigma(16)=16\;,\;\;\sigma(8)=8\;$ for any $\;\sigma\text{Aut}\,(K/\Bbb Q)\;$ , since $\;8,\,16\in\Bbb Q\;$ , but I can't parse those equalities in that "solution": it doesn't make any sense to me...What is true is that $\;\sigma^2\neq Id.\;$, and thus $\;\text{Aut}\,(K/\Bbb Q)\cong\Bbb Z_4\;$ ... You need to write to Harvard and ask them what the hell they meant.

Answer (score 4):

This is a special case of a more general result:

**Theorem**: *Let $\zeta = e^{2\pi i/n}$ where $n$ is a positive integer and let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$. Then the extension $K\supset \mathbb{Q}$ is Galois and the Galois group $\textrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ the group of reduced residue classes modulo $n$*.

Your question corresponds to simpler case when $n$ is prime, say $p$. In this case we can see that the minimal polynomial of $\zeta$ is $$\Phi_{p}(x) = (x^{p} - 1)/(x - 1) = x^{p - 1} + x^{p - 2} + \dots + x + 1$$ and its roots are given by $\zeta, \zeta^{2}, \dots,\zeta^{p - 1}$. As noted in your question the automorphisms of $K$ which fix $\mathbb{Q}$ are those which map $\zeta$ to each of these roots and hence there are $(p - 1)$ such automorphisms.

To prove that the group of these automorphisms is cyclic we need to know that for any prime $p$ there is a positive integer $g$ such that the numbers $g, g^{2}, \dots, g^{p - 1}$ modulo $p$ are all different and lead to $1, 2, \dots, p - 1$ but not necessarily in that order. Such a number $g$ is called a *primitive root* of $p$. Thus the roots $\zeta, \zeta^{2}, \dots, \zeta^{p - 1}$ can be rewritten as $$\zeta^{g}, \zeta^{g^{2}}, \dots, \zeta^{g^{p - 1}}$$ Let $\sigma(\zeta) = \zeta^{g}$ be one non-identity automorphism of $K$ which fixes $\mathbb{Q}$. Then $\sigma^{i}(\zeta) = \zeta^{g^{i}}$ so that $\sigma, \sigma^{2}, \dots, \sigma^{p - 1}$ gives all the needed automorphisms. Thus the group of automorphisms of $K$ which fix $\mathbb{Q}$ is cyclic with generator $\sigma$.

In your case $p = 5$ and we can choose $g = 2$ as $2, 4, 8, 16$ mod $5$ is $2, 4, 3, 1$.

---

For general $n$ the Galois group $\textrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q}) \cong (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ is cyclic only when there exists a primitive root $g$ of $n$ and that happens only when $n = 2, 4, p^{k}, 2p^{k}$ where $p$ is odd prime and $k$ is any positive integer.

---

The notation in your question is confusing. $\sigma_{i}$ is defined by $\sigma_{i}(\zeta) = \zeta^{i}$. Then $$\sigma_{2}^{4}(\zeta) = \sigma_{2}^{3}(\zeta^{2}) = \zeta^{16} = \sigma_{1}(\zeta^{16}) = \zeta$$ and this is what he writes as $\sigma_{2}^{4} = \sigma_{1}(16)$. The equation $$\sigma_{2}^{4} = \sigma_{1}(16) = \sigma_{3}(8)\sigma_{2} = \sigma_{4}^{2}$$ is a shorthand notation for $$\sigma_{2}^{4}(\zeta) = \sigma_{1}(\zeta^{16}) = \sigma_{3}(\zeta^{8})\sigma_{2}(\zeta) = \sigma_{4}^{2}(\zeta)$$

Comment: Thanks Paramanand, 1) I was wondering why you picked g = 2. Is it an appropriate choice for in general for other questions? 2)I have been told that K/Q is only Galois if "the other roots" are in Q. But the other roots are not in Q, so why can we send zeta to other roots? (I know that another way to check for Galois extension is to show the order of the Galois extension is the same as the dimension of [K:Q]). I look forward to your reply.

Comment: @Wilson: it is galois if other roots are also in $K$ so that $K$ is a splitting field of the polynomial concerned. The choice of $g$ depends on $p$ and you need to check manually (as i have checked powers of $g = 2$ modulo $p = 5$). What is guaranteed is that for a prime $p$ some $g$ exists and that is all we need.

Comment: @Wilson: I have also given some explanation to the confusing notation used in your question at the end of my answer. hope that helps. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up Paramanand!! 1) So if I am told to list out the elements of the Galois group, it would be {σ1,σ2,σ3,σ4} where σ1(2)=2; σ2(4)=4;σ(8)=3, σ(16)=1?. 2) I am trying to reason why K/Q is Galois using the idea from Problem 12 (http://www.math.harvard.edu/~ctm/home/text/class/harvard/123/02/html/home/solns/sset-11.pdf). Based on what you said, we could always find a Galois group? But this was not the case for Problem 12. I am sorry...but my professor only introduced this without giving us any practice problems and my exam is in 3 days!

Comment: @Wilson: A field extension $K/F$ is Galois if $K$ is the splitting field of some polynomial in $F[x]$. Thus $K$ should contain all the roots of that polynomial. For example $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})/\mathbb{Q}$ is not Galois as it does not contain all roots of $x^{3} - 2 = 0$, but $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})/\mathbb{Q}$ is a Galois extension as it contains both the roots of $x^{2} - 2 = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

You can factorize $x^5-1=(x-1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)$, and the latter factor is irreducible and its roots over $\mathbb{C}$ are $\zeta^i$ for $1\le i\le 4$.  Therefore the splitting field is indeed $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta]$ and it is easy to check that $\sigma:\zeta\rightarrow\zeta^i$ is indeed an automorphism (check the axioms if you like).  Furthermore, these are the only automorphisms since $\zeta$ must be sent to another root of its minimal polynomial.

Admittedly the second part of the solution seems a bit strange, but one can probably reword it in the following way.  Consider the automorphism $\sigma_i:\zeta\rightarrow\zeta^i$.  Then $\sigma_1$ is the identity and we will calculate the order of $\sigma_2$.  We have $\sigma_2^2=\sigma_4$ and $\sigma_2^3 = \sigma_3$, so the order can't be $2$ or $3$ and thus must be $4$. (You can check that $\sigma_2^4=\sigma_1$ if you like).  Because the only other group of order $4$ (besides $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$) doesn't have a n element of order $4$, we're done.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your explanation. I am still a little confused with how σ2(σ2)^2=σ4. I thought σ2(e) = e^2 => (σ2)^2(e) = e^4 => σ2(σ2)^2(e) = e^8. But how does this equal to σ4? Thanks.

Comment: Also the σ1 = identity = 0? :) Thanks!!

Comment: Yes, $\sigma_1$ is the identity.  I think you misinterpreted the period as a dot - I've edited it to make it clearer.